# Is It Possible To Run A Command In A Running Cronjob

Tags: cron, minecraft

On my computer Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS I'm hosting a minecraft server that starts and stops automatically using crontab. is there a way I can type a command (/tellraw ... for example) anytime by running a shell scrip or something?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what do you exactly want to do. Try to clarify it. Do you want to send a command to a running server? As it's a server, there is probably an appropriate client that you can use for that purpose. You connect with a client to a running server and send the command.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) And provide us more details.

Comment: There are many different Minecraft servers. Each runs differently. Each is controlled differently. Help us to help you.